# How do I encode text to utf-16be "correctly"?

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to reproduce the (ABC) example from this site:
https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/html2015/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2Fpdfmark_Basic%2FBookmarks_OUT.htm

> For example, the Unicode string for (ABC) is <FEFF004100420043>.

But when I try to reproduce just the ABC, I get:

```
"ABC".encode(encoding="utf-16be")
Out[29]: b'\x00A\x00B\x00C'
```

I think I am misunderstanding a larger concept, but I am unsure what to look for.

I need to produce the exact same string, so for the minimal example above I would need: `004100420043`. The question therefore is: How do I get from one representation to the other?

Given the already existing answer by gog:
How do I get from `b'\xFE\xFF\x00\x41\x00\x42\x00\x43'` to `FEFF004100420043`

Comment: You posted the exact same byte values using different formatting. `b'\xFE\xFF\x00\x41\x00\x42\x00\x43'` is the binary string representation of the values `FE-FF-00-41-00-42-00-43`. UTF16 is a way of encoding characters to byte values. What matters is those byte values, not the formatting used by developers to represent them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they want BOM as well, so

```
import codecs
result = codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE + "ABC".encode(encoding="utf-16be")
```

which would be

```
b'\xfe\xff\x00A\x00B\x00C'
```

which is the same as

```
b'\xFE\xFF\x00\x41\x00\x42\x00\x43'
```

To convert that to the hex format, use

```
result.hex()
```

optionally followed by `.upper()`

Comment: Thank you. Since I am using the result as an input for another program, I need to convert them into the exact format. How do I do that? Or more precise how do I get from `b'\xFE\xFF\x00\x41\x00\x42\x00\x43'` to `FEFF004100420043`

Comment: @Natan: `result.hex()`

Comment: @Natan why do you care how the bytes are displayed? You should care about the byte values only. The values are identical. Unicode ins't some kind of escape sequences, it's a way of mapping characters to bytes. The bytes are the same in both cases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: you care about these things when you're generating a program in another language, in this case PostScript. AFAIK, `<hex>` is the postscript syntax for binary literals.

Answer (score 1):

Using `utf-16be` codification, you need to use a combination of `codecs` module and the `hex()` built-in Python function to get the desired output format of the encoded string:

```
import codecs
result = codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE + "ABC".encode(encoding="utf-16be")
print(result, [i for i in result], result.hex())
```

**Output:**

```
b'\xfe\xff\x00A\x00B\x00C' [254, 255, 0, 65, 0, 66, 0, 67] feff004100420043
```

As you can see, Python encodes stings in `bytes` format. WHen you traverse those values, you can get its integer value and thus convert it to hexadecimal, which is the correct output in this case.